# $.each pass value to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I don't know how to search this problem in Stackoverflow it gives different solutions and does not relate to my problem. So I'll be needing your help again guys.

**Values of variable obj:**

```
item.title = Title1 and Title2

item.description = Description1 and Description2
```

**HTML FILE:**

```
function test_pop() {
    var fb_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var v_id = "xxxxxxxx";

    $.post('http://mysite.com/myfile.php', {fb_id: fb_id, v_id: v_id}, function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(obj,function(index, item){
           achievement = "You Obtained " + item.title + " " + item.description;
           achievement_pop(achievement);
        });
    });
}
```

**achievement_pop function:**

```
function achievement_pop(data) {
    $("#achievement_popup").html(data).show(); //DIV that should show up
}
```

So the problem is, when the div shows up, it only outputs:

```
    <div> <!-- Imagine that this content is inside a DIV -->
**You Obtained Title2 Description2**

    </div>
```

But my desire output is:

```
    <div> <!-- Imagine that this content is inside a DIV -->

**You Obtained Title1 Description1**

**You Obtained Title2 Description2**

    </div>
```

Hope you guys help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `html` function is replacing the whole content of the div, it's not just adding.

A solution would be to replace

```
$("#achievement_popup").html(data).show();
```

with

```
$("#achievement_popup").html($("#achievement_popup").html()+data).show();
```

But it's a little heavy. Personally I would first build the html and use the `html` function only once.

Answer (score 2):

Use `append()` to add to end of element and not replace the content completely with `html()`

Or if you want to replace the existing content with all the new content at once:

```
/* start with empty string*/
var achievement='';
$.each(obj,function(index, item){
    /* add to string on each pass of loop - can use any html you want here*/
     achievement += "You Obtained " + item.title + " " + item.description +'<br>';
});
/* update element once all data parsed*/
 achievement_pop(achievement);
```

Parsing to string and making one update is the most efficient from processing standpoint